# Invisible boundaries on PRAAT?

Tags: praat

I used P2FA to insert all of these boundaries. For some reason, there is an invisible boundary. You can see this is part of the selection. I would like to hand-correct the interval labelled B (on tier 1), but I'm unable to do so. I tried dragging the left boundary of B to the left, but it doesn't let me. I think it has something to do with this invisible boundary.

Thanks. I hope this makes sense.

[image: There seems to be an invisible boundary that I can't delete. What's going on?]

Comment: I've encountered the same problem with P2FA before. I'm not quite sure anymore how I solved it, but have you tried removing the left boundary of the B interval and then setting a new one?

Comment: I've seen similar issues sometimes when TextGrids have been converted from some other format, when interval timestamps overlap with those of their neighbours. You might want to save it to a text file and manually check it to make sure that there are no such overlaps.